# Why is the following UIAlertView code not working

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I'm trying to get the following working, this example appears on a few websites but i just can't seem to get it working.

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Yes, like this" message:@"What are you looking at?" cancelButtonTitle:@"Leave me alone" otherButtonTitles:@"Button 1",@"Button 2",nil];
    [alert showWithDismissHandler:^(NSInteger selectedIndex, BOOL didCancel) {
        if (didCancel) {
            NSLog(@"User cancelled");
            return;
        }
        switch (selectedIndex) {
            case 1:
                NSLog(@"1 selected");
                break;
            case 2:
                NSLog(@"2 selected");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }];
```

The warnings I'm getting are

No visible @interface for 'UIAlertView' declares the selector 'initWithTitle:message:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:'

No visible @interface for 'UIAlertView' declares the selector 'showWithDismissHandler:'

Properly a really daft question but what am i missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The signature is not correct. You missed delegate.

```
– initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:
```

The standard `UIAlertView` does not have `showWithDismissHandler` method. If you copied some code from internet, likely you will need to download some third party package that supports `UIAlertView` with `block` callback (there are quite a few of them).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Peter is right! The first warning is because the signature is not correct:

```
– initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:
```

and what you trying to do here is to do something when the `alertview is dismissed` and the `method` you are using `is not available`. Implement `UIAlertViewDelegate` and then use any of these methods to do what you are trying to do here.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Here's the link to UIAlertView delegate reference:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you using something like [`UBAlertView`](https://github.com/stavash/UIBAlertView), by any chance? If so, you need to instantiate a `UBAlertView`, not a `UIAlertView`:

```
UBAlertView *alert = [[UBAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Yes, like this"
                                                message:@"What are you looking at?"
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Leave me alone"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Button 1",@"Button 2",nil];
[alert showWithDismissHandler:^(NSInteger selectedIndex, BOOL didCancel) {
    ... etc ...
```

(I like to put line breaks in long method calls to make them more readable.)